# Prevent JK-FF Counter to start from beginning after reaching maximum

Tags: flipflop, counter

how can I prevent a counter based on JK-FF (up-counter, up/down-counter) from jumping back to zero after it reached the maximum.

For Up-Counter:
It should count up until it reaches maximum and stay there until I reset the JKFF.

For Up/Down-Counter
It should count up until it reaches maximum and stay there until I reset the JKFF.
It should count down until it reaches minimum and stay there until I reset the JKFF.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the counter when the max is reached. You can do that by passing the clock through a AND gate down to the clock input. The other input is the internal state based enable which you create with an n-input AND gate for detecting max and a n-input NOR gate for min.

When clamping you add the (possibly inverted) direction input pin to the and gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCv0fA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Insertion of some gates into the clk line is not good. Better is use an `enable` input on the Counter